# Receiving webhook data and save them in db

Tags: php, webhooks

I want to handle data, that is sended by a trello webhook.
There for the webhook posts to a url like site.com/tracker.php

In the tracker.php I want to save the data in a database. For that I need to get some params.

This is a example of the code I receive (https://trello.com/docs/gettingstarted/webhooks.html):

```
{
   "action": {
      "id":"51f9424bcd6e040f3c002412",
      "idMemberCreator":"4fc78a59a885233f4b349bd9",
      "data": {
         "board": {
            "name":"Trello Development",
            "id":"4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c"
         },
         "card": {
            "idShort":1458,
            "name":"Webhooks",
            "id":"51a79e72dbb7e23c7c003778"
         },
         "voted":true
      },
      "type":"voteOnCard",
      "date":"2013-07-31T16:58:51.949Z",
      "memberCreator": {
         "id":"4fc78a59a885233f4b349bd9",
         "avatarHash":"2da34d23b5f1ac1a20e2a01157bfa9fe",
         "fullName":"Doug Patti",
         "initials":"DP",
         "username":"doug"
      }
   },
   "model": {
      "id":"4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c",
      "name":"Trello Development",
      "desc":"Trello board used by the Trello team to track work on Trello.  How meta!\n\nThe development of the Trello API is being tracked at https://trello.com/api\n\nThe development of Trello Mobile applications is being tracked at https://trello.com/mobile",
      "closed":false,
      "idOrganization":"4e1452614e4b8698470000e0",
      "pinned":true,
      "url":"https://trello.com/b/nC8QJJoZ/trello-development",
      "prefs": {
         "permissionLevel":"public",
         "voting":"public",
         "comments":"public",
         "invitations":"members",
         "selfJoin":false,
         "cardCovers":true,
         "canBePublic":false,
         "canBeOrg":false,
         "canBePrivate":false,
         "canInvite":true
      },
      "labelNames": {
         "yellow":"Infrastructure",
         "red":"Bug",
         "purple":"Repro'd",
         "orange":"Feature",
         "green":"Mobile",
         "blue":"Verified"
      }
   }
}
```

And this is my current tracker.php file:

```
<?php

$json = $_POST["actions"];
$action = json_decode($json);
$action_id = $action->id;
$card_id = $action->data->card->id;
var_dump($array);
```

My questions:

- Is the $_POST["actions"] right? Or what do I need inside the []
- Is the way I want to get the $action->data->card->id right?
- Is there any way to see the result of the var_dump? Dont know how to see the result of an webhook post..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had to use this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$action = json_decode($json, true);
```

As far as I understand the json request is not automaticly split into the $_POST. Thus you have to use the input itself.

The true-parameter in json_decode is needed to get an associative array. Without it I only got an empty array.

Comment: What about security? How to be sure if response is sent by trello only?

Comment: @DavinderKumar that's a different question. You should ask that seperatly and provide enough information about it.

Comment: @DavinderKumar I think we could get that from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` (if it's set, else deny) and verify it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to check if the received data is a JSON formatted or not.

```
if($json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true)) {
    print_r($json);
    $data = $json;
} else {
    print_r($_POST);
    $data = $_POST;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in laravel with php8>

in routes/api.php:

```
            Route::middleware(['checkPublicServiceTokens'])
                ->group(function () {
                    Route::post('/webhook', [
                        WhatsAppController::class,
                        'webhook'
                    ])->name('whatsapp.webhook');
                });
```

in app/http/kernel.php in routeMiddleware section:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
```

add this:

```
    'checkPublicServiceTokens' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckPublicServiceTokens::class,
```

in app/http/Middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!$request->input('public-webhook-token') || $this->isTokenValid($request)) {
        return apiResponse()->errors(__('exception.access_denied_public'))
            ->status(Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)
            ->get();
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

in lang/en/exception.php

```
'access_denied_public' => 'authorized token as webhook token',
```

in your controller:
public function webhook(WhatsAppWebhookRequest $request): JsonResponse
{
$item = app()->make(WhatsAppWebhookRepository::class)->store($request->all());
return apiResponse()->data($item)->status(Response::HTTP_CREATED)->get();
}

in store method in your implementation :

```
public function store(array $data): WhatsAppWebhook
{
    $payload = array("payload"=>json_encode($data));
    $item = new WhatsAppWebhook($payload);
    $item->save();
    return $item;
}
```